# Calling method that exists in child classes but not in parent class

Tags: java, oop, class-design, instanceof

```
public class Parent {
    ....
}

public class Child1 extends Parent {
    ....
    public void foo() {
        ....
    }
}

public class Child2 extends Parent {
    ....
    public void foo() {
        ....
    }
}
```

Here method `foo()` only exists in the Child classes and CAN NOT be added to the Parent class (not even abstract method). In this situation when I want to call the `foo()` method on `obj` which is `Parent` class's reference then I need to use `intanceof` with multiple `if..else` which I want to avoid.

```
Parent obj = ...// Object of one of the child classes
obj.foo();
```

**EDIT:** I Need to use type of `obj` as `Parent` only. Else I will not be able to call methods on obj which exists in Parent class.

---

**My Solution:** The approach that I am thinking is to define an interface say `FooInterface` with `foo()` method and let all the child classes implement it, then I could just type cast the `obj` to that interface and call foo() method like this:

```
if(obj instanceof FooInterface){
    ((FooInterface)obj).foo();
}
```

Is there a better approach ? Or any improvement to this one?

Comment: Whenever a method is common in the child, it should be place in parent. Why u r not putting that method in abstract class??

Comment: I CAN NOT change `Parent` class, as I do not manage it.

Comment: Then use interface which is stated in the solution given below in the answers.

Comment: Can you introduce an intermediary class between Parent and Child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach that I am finally taking is to define an interface say `FooInterface` with `foo()` method and let all the child classes implement it, then I could just type cast the obj to that interface and call `foo()` method like this:

```
Parent obj = ...// Object of one of the child classes
.....
if(obj instanceof FooInterface){
    ((FooInterface)obj).foo();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with parent object reference until an unless method is declared in parent class/interface itself.

You have to downcast it to child class because **parent class/interface doesn't have any knowledge about the child class other than the contract defined between them.**

Here `contract` means `abstract methods`.

---

you can try in this way where there is no need to put a check it.

```
FooInterface sc =new Child1();
sc.foo();

...

interface FooInterface{
    void foo();
}

public class Parent {

}

public class Child1 extends Parent implements FooInterface{

    public void foo() {

    }
}

public class Child2 extends Parent implements FooInterface{

    public void foo() {

    }
}
```

Comment: With this solution I will not be able to call methods on `sc` which exists in Parent class. I edited my question to mention this. Thanks.

Comment: have you made `Child1` implements `FooInterface` same for `Child2`?

Comment: This is what I mentioned in My Solution, only difference is that in my solution, reference is of type `Parent` and thus I need to use `instanceof` once to see if it is of type `FooInterface`.

Comment: so you don't want to change your design then its not possible as I told you *parent class/interface doesn't have any knowledge about the child class.* how would parent class/interface know that child has created x methods?

Comment: How about my solution that I had mentioned in the question? it does solve my problem. But is good approach is what I want to know?

Answer (score 1):

The polymorphism is applied on object reference, not a type. When you call

```
FooInterface obj = ...// Object of one of the child classes
obj.foo();
```

the child class method `foo()` is called.

Comment: Look at the OP question again. `Parent` doesn't have any `foo()` method.

Comment: How can you call a method on the reference of interface where interface has not declared that method? Look at my post.

Comment: @Braj Now you should read OP question again, the interface define a method foo.

Comment: Read this line not solution part **Here method foo() only exists in the Child classes and CAN NOT be added to the Parent class (not even abstract method)**

Comment: @Roman C, the interface is part of my solution And what am asking is whether my solution is good or is there a better way to do it.

Comment: @Braj read more that OP notes: `The approach that I am thinking is to define an interface say FooInterface with foo()`

Comment: @Braj What a code review? Are you not a java programmer? Or anything wrong with the format the answer? Or you just kidding me out there?

Comment: @RomanC your answer is best suited for this condition. +1 for this approach.

Comment: @Learner One more comment to you, when designing your classes consider coding to interfaces, not classes.

Comment: @RomanC, With this solution I will not be able to call methods on `obj` which exists in `Parent` class. Yes, I understand advantage of code to interface but this is legacy code and I CAN NOT modify `Parent` class.

Comment: @Learner if you need a parent class then typecast it directly or use a method in the interface that return a parent type. Why there isn't this in the question that you want to use parent? See you have another incomplete answer from %Braj.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to typecast only then there is no need of adding interface. You can typecast it to your desired class and call the method. Example

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        SuperClass sc =new Child1();
        if(sc instanceof Child1)//Do same for Child2
        ((Child1)sc).foo();
    }
}

class SuperClass {

}

class Child1 extends SuperClass{
    public void foo(){
        System.out.println("From child1");
    }
}

class Child2 extends SuperClass{
    public void foo(){
        System.out.println("From child2");
    }
}
```

Output : 
From child1

Comment: Well, that's what I think is not a good approach and hence don't want to use it. If there are multiple child classes then it would be ugly. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement an `AbstractChild` inheriting from `Parent` and then extend this class instead of `Parent`:

```
public class Parent {
    ....
}

public abstract class AbstractChild extends Parent{

    public abstract void foo();

}



public class Child1 extends AbstractChild {
    ....
    public void foo() {
        ....
    }
}

public class Child2 extends AbstractChild {
    ....
    public void foo() {
        ....
    }
}
```

So you need to only check if your instance is `instanceof AbstractChild`.