# How can I access the method of the child class from parent reference?

Tags: android

Lets say we have this:

```
class A
  {
      func printTheValueA()
         {
            print("A")
         }

  }
  class B:A
  {
    func printTheValueB()
      {
        print("")
       }
   }
class C {
var a:A = B()
a.printTheValueB()
}
```

As in above code is it possible to use the method of class B from the reference of class A?

Comment: just cast the class A to B

Comment: Is it possible `var a:A = B()` think twice!

Comment: Please don't use the Android tag for a question that has nothing to do with Android.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23730145/8101634

Comment: made a mistake, I was to ask if I can var a:B = A()

Answer (score 0):

Don't what you are trying but the code should be

```
open class A
  {
       fun printTheValueA()
         {
            print("A")
         }         
  }
  class B:A()
  {
       fun printTheValueB()
      {
        print("B")
       }
    }


fun main() {
    println("Hello, world!!!")
    var a:B = B()
    if(a is A)
    a.printTheValueB()

}
```

you can try it [here](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)

Comment: thanks for answering @Doc but i wanted to know if child can have instance of parent and access to the method. But after checking I found out that there will be compile time error.